# Change dragged element appearance during .Net MAUI draggesturerecognizer operation

Tags: drag-and-drop, element, maui, appearance

How do I change the appearance of the XAML element that is displayed while being dragged during a drag & drop operation in .Net MAUI?

Maybe I should ask to what extent the appearance of the dragged visual can be changed?

Currently the dragged visual is basically a slightly transparent copy of the XAML element on which the DragGestureRecognizer is implemented. I'd like to replace that visual completely, or at least resize it.

I've adapted [this](https://github.com/borisoprit/DragdropMaui) example for an MVVM implementation, but I can't seem to find a way to change the appearance of the dragged visual.

Thx

Comment: I've never tried it, but see [Drag and drop / Build a data package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop?view=net-maui-7.0#build-a-data-package). If you get this to work, please add an answer showing the working code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `DragStartingCommand` which is executed when a drag gesture is first recognized.

Here is the code in .xmal file. I create a rectangle.

```
<Rectangle Stroke="Red"
           Fill="DarkBlue"
           StrokeThickness="4"
           HeightRequest="200"
           WidthRequest="200"
           x:Name="myrec" >
    <Rectangle.GestureRecognizers>
        <DragGestureRecognizer DragStarting="OnDragStarting" />
    </Rectangle.GestureRecognizers>
</Rectangle>
```

Here is the code behind. I drag the element then it will set the height to 12.

```
void OnDragStarting(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
{
    
    Shape shape = (sender as Element).Parent as Shape;
    e.Data.Properties.Add("Square", new Square(shape.Width, shape.Height));
    myrec.HeightRequest = 12;
}
```

More commands you can use by refering to [Add drag and drop gesture recognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop?view=net-maui-7.0#enable-drag)